# My Xamarin Forms app is getting crash for unknown reason

Tags: xamarin.forms, crash, segmentation-fault

The following message is shown in the Output window of Visual Studio:

> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.

The app crashes when navigating to the view that contains a `ListView`. This happens only for the first time and then after that, there are no issues.

- Is there a way to find out the reason behind the crash?

My Xamarin Forms version is 2.5.0.280555

Comment: Which platform? Sounds like iOS error. You can open the logs by going to `Help` > `Xamarin` > `OpenLogs` in vs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The crash occurred in Android.

Comment: btw, you might get a more elaborated error log if the debugger holds after the crash and displays the "Continue" button. Hit the continue button and see if the Output window displays more lines

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger is not getting hold and the app is crashing immediately forcing the debugging to stop completely. Please let me know your assumptions on the occurrence of the crash. Could this be due to the coding or is this a framework level issue?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to tell you this, but might be due to you calling a method that does not exist on the current API level you are building it on. Are you talking about Android.Widget.ListView or Xamarin.Forms.ListView? If you're working inside the Android project, then I guess some method of you is causing the error. Check your android version and see if the method that throws this is available on this one.

Comment: Thank you @Csharpest for looking into my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by creating a new solution once again. In the second attempt I didn't install 'RestClient' NuGet package. I think that was the package which caused the issue. I've seen many developers asking for help in solving sporadic crashes. My suggestion is to double check all the NuGet packages.